# unity: how to make instantiated gameobject to have rectTransform of the canvas? (c#)

Tags: unity, c#, transformation

```
public GameObject canvas;  // the canvas

GameObject changerSign = Instantiate(changerPopup, 
    new Vector3(235, 350, 0),
    this.transform.rotation);
changerSign.transform.SetParent(canvas.transform);
```

this will make a UI at the screen. while it does make the object as wanted, the rect transform won't get fixed(?) to the newly set parent(the Canvas), but instead to where it was first made. how could I get it under canvas's rect transform? could be some too basic question, but couldn't find any answer anywhere so far :(

Comment: you should make it child of canvas.you don't need rotation in canvas ... so it's better that you change `transform.rotatoin `to `Quaternion.identity`

Comment: I did make it a child of a canvas, but for some reason don't follow the canvas rect transform;;;;;;;;;; and thanks for the rotation advise, but that don't seems to be the issue atm

Comment: but i test it...works correctly.please insert screenshot of for displaying the problem.

Comment: oh yeah... solved it, forgot to add the answer to it. using localPosition worked. still confused why it needs localposition value when it's labeled child of the canvas, but solved anyway.

Answer (score 1):

for childing there are two Parameter in `Setparent`:

> **parent :**   The parent Transform to use.
>
> **worldPositionStays:**    If true, the parent-relative position, scale and rotation are modified such that the object keeps the same world space position, rotation and scale as before.https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.SetParent.html

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class NewBehaviourScript : MonoBehaviour {
    public GameObject canvas;  // the canvas
    public GameObject changerPopup; // the UI prefab

    void Start () {
        GameObject changerSign = Instantiate(changerPopup,Vector2.zero,Quaternion.identity);//it's better that you change transform.rotatoin to Quaternion.identity

        //here you need to childing your Instantiated prefab to canvas
        //there are two way of doing it:

        //1.child it without adapting with canvas(worldPositionStays = true , this is mean keep Previous position, rotation, scale)
        //If true, the parent-relative position, scale and rotation are modified such that the object keeps the same world space position, rotation and scale as before.
        changerSign.transform.SetParent(canvas.transform, true);
        //equivalent:
        changerSign.transform.parent = canvas.transform;

        //2.child it with adapting with canvas(worldPositionStays = false , this is mean set Previous position)

        changerSign.transform.SetParent(canvas.transform,false);
        //equivalent1:
        changerSign.transform.SetParent(canvas.transform,canvas.transform.parent);
        //equivalent2:
        //first child it by using first way , next adapt it with canvas
        changerSign.transform.parent = canvas.transform;
        RectTransform rt = changerSign.GetComponent<RectTransform>();
        rt.anchoredPosition = rt.transform.position;// or use this rt.localPosition = rt.transform.position;

        //next you can set position by localPosition :
        rt.localPosition = new Vector2(50,50);
        }
    }
```

for more information there is useful discuss [here](https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/problem-with-instantiate-ui-prefabs.271345/)

---

you should use `localPosition` instead of `position` in canvas...what is difference?

```
position        The position of the transform in world space. 
localPosition   Position of the transform relative to the parent transform.
```

http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/ScriptReference/Transform.html

---

Note:If you want set position for your prefab in canvas ,I prefer instead of calculating suitable position by `new Vector(x,y)`, it's better to use built-in RectTransform's AnchorPositions

[image]

but how to access RectTransform's left, right, top, bottom positions via code?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class RectAnchors : MonoBehaviour {
    public GameObject canvas;  // the canvas
    public GameObject changerPopup; // the UI prefab

    public enum SetRect{Center,Left,Right,Top,Bottom,LB,RB,LT,RT}
    public SetRect setrect;


    void Start () {
        GameObject changerSign = Instantiate(changerPopup, 
            Vector2.zero,
            Quaternion.identity);

        changerSign.transform.parent = canvas.transform;
        RectTransform rt = changerSign.GetComponent<RectTransform>();
        float left   =  rt.offsetMin.x + 100;
        float right  = -rt.offsetMax.x;
        float top    = -rt.offsetMax.y;
        float bottom =  rt.offsetMin.y + 100;

        switch(setrect){
        case SetRect.Center: rt.anchoredPosition = new Vector3 (0, 0);
            break;
        case SetRect.Bottom: rt.anchoredPosition = new Vector3 (0, bottom);
            break;
        case SetRect.Left: rt.anchoredPosition = new Vector3 (left, 0);
            break;
        case SetRect.Right: rt.anchoredPosition = new Vector3 (right, 0);
            break;
        case SetRect.Top:
            rt.anchoredPosition = new Vector3 (0, top);
            break;
        case SetRect.LB: rt.anchoredPosition = new Vector3 (left, bottom);
            break;
        case SetRect.RB: rt.anchoredPosition = new Vector3 (right, bottom);
            break;
        case SetRect.LT: rt.anchoredPosition = new Vector3 (left, top);
            break;
        case SetRect.RT:
            rt.anchoredPosition = new Vector3 (right, top);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

well i feel silly after knowing this :P

have to specify the parent for the rect transform too.

```
changerSign.GetComponent<RectTransform>().parent = canvas.GetComponent<RectTransform>();
```

adding this works.

edit: problem wasn't these, but instead was the fact I was supposed to use transform.localPosition. 
I don't understand why despite the fact it's a child of a canvas, but it's solved. Thanks to everyone answered trying to help me.

Comment: You can also specify the parent in the `Instantiate` call. `Instantiate(changerPopup, new Vector3(235, 350, 0), this.transform.rotation, canvas.transform);` Also you don't have to call `GetComponent` for the RectTransform, RectTransform inherits from Transform, thus the `parent` property and the `transform` properties on other components will work just fine.

Comment: OK..... Now i'm REEEALY CONFUSED >:(

for some reason when I re-run the game the rect transform is not on the canvas again..... what the......

Comment: and @Draco18s thank you for the extra info but somehow that's not working either :( .... i was so happy with the fact I done it after 4 hrs of struggling and now this .... ㅠㅠ